# Mapbox WMTS support in OpenLayers

Tags: mapbox, openlayers

I have created a Mapbox style using Mapbox Studio and set it to be used over WMTS. The URL of the style is:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/username/styleId/wmts?access_token=token

where `styleId`, `username` and `token` are variable fields.

When I try to create a WMTS layer in OpenLayers using the url above, the **tileGrid** is created successfully using `createFromCapabilitiesMatrixSet` but I get a response error `Invalid query param layer` from Mapbox.

After some investigation, I noticed that:

1. The response error persists for all query parameters that are appended from OpenLayers when creating the tile load function. It looks like that Mapbox does not recognise them properly.
2. OpenLayers website and Mapbox also give examples on using XYZ layers for integration between them.

So, is this some kind of unsupported feature of OpenLayers or do I need to configure anything additional when creating the WMTS OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler to set up as a standard OpenLayers XYZ layer using

```
  url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/username/styleId/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=token'
```

as in the examples.

Mapbox provides WMTS support for compatibility with some other systems. It can also be used in OpenLayers, the setup would be

```
  var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();
  fetch('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/username/styleId/wmts?access_token=token').then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
  }).then(function(text) {

      var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.WMTS(
              ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(parser.read(text), {
                  layer: 'styleId',
                  matrixSet: 'EPSG:3857'
              })
          )
      });

      ....
      ....
      ....
      ....

  });
```

Both methods will ultimately load the same tile urls, so there's no advantage in using WMTS where XYZ is supported.

Comment: I am already using the `optionsFromCapabilities` method to create WMTS options and pass them to the WMTS constructor `ol.source.WMTS` but the request to the Mapbox API fails with the error message that I describe above.

Comment: It works for me.  layer is a required option in the call, and the only valid value is your mapbox styleId.

Comment: Here's a demo using a style I set up to display contours from Mapbox terrain on top of OSM http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/mapbox-wmts.htm

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mike. Your sample works indeed! I can see that you are asking for options dynamically. In my case, I keep the options of the layer locally, instead of requesting it each time from the URL. That is I have an object that contains `format`, `layer`, `matrixSet`, `projection`, `style` and `tileMatrixSet` and this object is used to feed the  `ol.source.WMTS` constructor.  By the way, I notice that in the demo, OpenLayers makes a XYZ source request internally.

Comment: That's because the mapbox wmtsGetCapabilities response defines the tile url as .../tiles/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow} so their WMTS service is just a "wrapper" for XYZ.